# Shopware 6 : Partial indexing

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

Is there a way to make a partial index of products by CLI?
Because bin/console dal:refresh:index always generates complete indexing (e.g. via Queue/Messenger).

But if i just update 1-2 products by API it seems, that the indexing is not triggered nor a message is left in enqueue to be consumed by messenger:consume.

Background: We are coding a middleware for an ERP and Shopware 6. When we send products via an API, it seems, that the indexing for this products isn't triggered nor the categories it belongs too. So you won't see the (updated version of the) product.

It's fine if you just have ~100 products but it is hard when it gets into a range of 20-50000 products

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the [indexing behavior `use-queue-indexing`](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTUx-bulk-payloads#performance). So the index will be done automatically, but still keeping a good performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already using use-queue-indexing. It is fine, if you have a low amount of products. But when it comes down to 20-50k products as mentioned, it also takes time. Even when running 2-4 message consumers.